# Using pybrain optimization algorithm to solve search problems

Tags: python, optimization, pybrain, hill-climbing

I recently started using pybrain library for classification problems using neural networks and with some struggle and documentation I made it work.

Now, I would like to use blackbox optimization algorithms from the same library, but not applied to classification.

Basically, I am trying to reproduce some result from Randy's blog http://www.randalolson.com/2015/02/03/heres-waldo-computing-the-optimal-search-strategy-for-finding-waldo/.

So, as a first step, I constructed supervised dataset with the following snippet:

```
ds = SupervisedDataSet(2, 2)
for row in range(len(waldo_df)):
    ds.addSample(inp=waldo_df.iloc[row][['Book', 'Page']], target=waldo_df.iloc[row][['X', 'Y']])
return ds
```

Now, one sample from the dataset looks like:

```
ds.getSample()
[array([ 5.,  8.]), array([ 3.51388889,  4.31944444])]
```

On the next step I would like to use HillClimber algorithm to find the optimal path:

```
ef = ds.evaluateModuleMSE
init_value = ds.getSample()
learner = HillClimber(evaluator=ef, initEvaluable=init_value, minimize=True)
learner.learn()
```

What I get back in exception:

```
/Users/maestro/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pybrain/datasets/supervised.pyc in evaluateModuleMSE(self, module, averageOver, **args)
 96         res = 0.
 97         for dummy in range(averageOver):
 ---> 98             module.reset()
 99             res += self.evaluateMSE(module.activate, **args)
100         return res/averageOver

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'reset'
```

Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong? The documentation on this is very sparse and even searching through the code base did not help.

Thanks

P.S. If I am reading the API correctly

```
class pybrain.optimization.HillClimber(evaluator=None, initEvaluable=None, **kwargs)
```

The simplest kind of stochastic search: hill-climbing in the fitness landscape.

the optimization algorithm needs to take only evaluator which in my case would be ds.evaluateModuleMSE

## Update

The whole code snippet is:

```
 import pandas as pd
 from pybrain.optimization import HillClimber
 from pybrain.datasets import SupervisedDataSet
 waldo_df = pd.read_csv('whereis-waldo-locations.csv')
 ds = SupervisedDataSet(2, 2)
 for row in range(len(waldo_df)):
   ds.addSample(inp=waldo_df.iloc[row][['Book', 'Page']],     target=waldo_df.iloc[row][['X', 'Y']])
 learner = HillClimber(evaluator=ds.evaluateModuleMSE,    initEvaluable=ds.getSample(), minimize=True)
```

Comment: How you create network? Could you give more code?

Comment: Do I need to create the network? This is not a classification problem. For example, on this page http://www.pybrain.org/docs/tutorial/optimization.html?highlight=blackboxoptimization there are optimization problems that do not require building networks. Perhaps I am grossly misunderstanding something.

Comment: @user1615070, all the code except reading the waldo dataset is present

Comment: @user1615070, I updated the question with exact problem to reproduce the issue

Comment: It's my fault - you don't need network for such things. I've reproduce your problem - but I don't have an idea yet. 
Have you look into code of pybrain?
I've put breakpoint before HillClimber initialization, and when I invoke ds.evaluateModuleMSE I've get the same error - so maybe it is problem with dataset?

Comment: This is problem with this "ds.evaluateModuleMSE" - it's not callable object. I've change it to function definition, and it pass to the next error in learning.